# Ffplay dual monitor setup

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, fullscreen, multiple-monitors

How can I launch ffplay on the second monitor in full screen mode?
I need to play a video file while analyzing video player output to get current position in the file being played.

Comment: I was able to do this by changing the default monitor in OS settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I understand I should have asked this question on Super User, but still...
The answer is to use **[mplayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/dload.html)**. It uses **ffmpeg**, but allows to position its window on any monitor with ease.

Answer (score 0):

Export DISPLAY=:0.0 ffplay -fs $rest_of_your_parameters_here

This will start ffplay in full screen on DISPLAY 0.0

Change 0.0 to select another monitor